# Operations with two lists as arrays

Tags: numpy

I need to perform an operation on two lists, `X`and `Y`, for which I must convert them into arrays, which I can make using:

```
M = [[] for i in range(len(mags))]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        M[i].append([np.array(X[i][j]) - np.array(Y[i][j])])
```

Now, I would expect to obtain an array for `M` which is `a` times `b` matrix. However, I am most confused with the data nesting that the operation produces. The elements of `M` are now a list-list-array-float64 (`M[][][][]`). What I would expect is to have a *list of lists*, i.e. `M[][]` that I can access to (and plot) in a simple loop function:

```
x = M ; Y = N
for i in range(len(M)):
    plt.scatter(x[i], y[i])
```

where `N` is a list of lists.

How can I obtain `M` simply as a list of lists? 
(Simply substracting of course produces the well-known message `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`)

(I read somewhere an analogy of this hierarchy of data as a postal address: 
`M[2][13][7][85]` could mean street `2`, block `13`, floor `7`, room `85`. I would only expect floor and room.).

How I produce `X` and `Y`:

```
X = [[] for i in range(len(mags))]
for i in range(len(mags)):
    for j in range(len(G[i])):
        X[i].append([G[i][j] - J[i][j]])
```

where `G` and `J` are matrices, both with same number of columns (`mags`) and different number of rows. How can I loop over columns which have a different length?

Comment: What is `mags`, `a`, `b`, 'N'? Could you please make your example fully executable? Furthermore you are converting lists into arrays into lists by appending and then passing it to `matplotlib` which prefers to take arrays but instead of passing the array or list to matplotlib you loop over it. The performance must be extremely slow. Please show some sample data and I bet that we can make it into two lines of code with a good performance.

Comment: Why didn't you use `M[i].append([X[i][j] - Y[i][j]])`.  What was the purpose of the `np.array(...)` wrapper?  Don't mix lists and arrays needlessly.

Comment: Give examples of `X` and `Y`.  I'm guessing they are lists of lists, but you need to be clear.  It's possible that you can make 2d arrays from them, and skip the iteration (`M=np.array(X)-np.array(Y)`).

Comment: I did try to simplify the code and highlight my doubt on the way python operates with two any arrays. I omitted the appending of data from a csv as it would complicate the question. `a` and `b` are simply the dimensions of my table. The main question is why substracting two lists (arrays) is producing something like `[[[array([1])], [array([2])], ...], ... ,[[[array([1])], [array([2])], ...]]` instead of just simply `[[1,2,...], ..., [1,2,...]]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Because I get the error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`.

Comment: If you wrap a list such as `[1]` in `np.array` you get `np.array([1])`.  You still haven't clearly described your lists, but now I suspect they are triple nested, e.g. `X=[[[1],[2]],...]`, so that `X[0][0]` still leaves you with a list, not a number.  `X[0][0][0]` might be required to do the math.

Comment: @hpaulj You are right, and it is because I don't have constructed `X` and `Y` properly. `X` is just the difference of two matrices, `G` and `J`, which have both a fixed number of columns (`mags`) and a number of rows that varies in each column. My problem is then how I wrote that loop. I am editing my question with the code snippet!

Comment: The solution: removing the brackets in the appending: `M[i].append(np.array(X[i][j]) - np.array(Y[i][j]))`instead of `M[i].append([np.array(X[i][j]) - np.array(Y[i][j])])`. That was ridiculously easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating one more list than necessary by adding extra brackets in the following piece of code:

```
M = [[] for i in range(len(mags))]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        M[i].append([np.array(X[i][j]) - np.array(Y[i][j])])
```

If you just change to:

```
M[i].append(np.array(X[i][j]) - np.array(Y[i][j]))
```

that should fix your problem.

The result will still be three levels deep however as the elements of `M` you are storing are lists of lists of floats `M[][][]`.

For your second question, it seems like you are doing it right. It would be better if your data was of the same shape but that is about all you can do if it isn't.